# C# .NET Core API| HTTP Response from API appears to be different from response recieved on client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, httpresponsemessage

I have recently migrated a .NET framework 4.7.2 web API to a .NET Core 3.1 AWS Lambda project (created with AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio), for the purpose of deploying my API to AWS.

I am currently in the process of getting it to work again after refactoring some parts of the old code to work with the new .NET Core targeted framework and it seems that my GET request responses are changing in transit from the API to my client-side Javascript.

The API is rather simple: it recieves a GET request, downloads an mp3, saves this file to a folder in the project directory called `App_Data` and returns this mp3 back to the client for it to be downloaded locally:

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class GetSongController : ControllerBase
    {
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetSong(string Url)
        {
            SongRequest songRequest = new SongRequest();
            songRequest.Url = Url;

            var pathInfo = await Task.Run(() => QueryLib(songRequest)); //downloads mp3
            var filePath = Path.Combine(pathInfo.FilePath, pathInfo.FileName);

            return await Task.Run(() => ResponseHelper.ConstructResponse(pathInfo, filePath, "audio/mpeg"));
        }
    }
```

The function `QueryLib` asynchronously downloads the mp3 and returns an instance of a class I created called `PathInfo`:

```cs
public class PathInfo
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public bool IsError { get; set; }
    }
```

The values of the above properties are as follows:

- `FilePath` - The absolute path of the downloaded file not including the file itself.
- `FileName` - The generated name of the downloaded file including its file extension (.mp3).
- `IsError` - A bool that is set to `true` if the download was erroneous.

The function `ResponseHelper.ConstructResponse` returns a `HttpResponseMessage`:

```cs
    public class ResponseHelper
    {
        public static HttpResponseMessage ConstructResponse(PathInfo pathInfo, string filePath, string ContentType)
        {
            //build response to send to client
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);

            var headers = result.Content.Headers;
            headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = pathInfo.FileName;
            headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(ContentType);
            headers.ContentLength = memoryStream.Length;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

This function gets a filestream of the downloaded file and sets the `.Content` property of the response message as such.

It then creates the `.Content.Headers` by setting a `Content-Disposition` of `"attachment"` and sets the filename. Then it sets the `Content-Type` to `"audio/mpeg"` which was passed as an argument. A length is then set and this response *(should be)* sent back to the client in exactly this structure.

However when I make a fetch request from my client to test this, the content type is `"application/json"` and the content disposition is `null`. This causes errors in my frontend when trying to download the file and I have not a clue why the response message completely changes.

I can see that the following line is logged in my Visual Studio console which confirms this change:

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 15867.4478ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8`

**To further add to my bewilderment**, if I open command prompt and `curl` the localhost to make the GET request instead of using my frontend to make the request, the data returned to me is what it is supposed to be:
[image: cmd output]

Cheers for reading all that. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: You shouldn't be returning a `HttpResponseMessage`, that sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @DavidG how so?

Comment: it's the old-school way of doing controllers. You say you are using .NET Core, why not use `IActionResult`?

Comment: @Andy `HttpResponseMessage` worked as expected when the API was using .NET Framework. I suspect It was probably used in whichever Youtube tutorial I was looking at when creating the API. I will look into using `IActionResult`